# Autolayout crash in iOS app

Tags: ios, crash, autolayout

I am getting a very strange crash issue my iOS app and this crash happens randomly. I did check my auto layout setup in storyboard and looks like everything is OK, but I am not sure what is the exact cause. I am attaching the screenshot of the stacktrace. Can someone help me in fixing this issue?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the autolayout feature and see if it still crashes ? ( to make sure it's really an autolayout problem )

Comment: @CamilleR: Sorry for the late reply, I didn't do that yet, but I am planning to rework on my auto layout.